# Tent map is topologically transitive

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Let $T:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the function $Tx= 2x$, if $ x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ and $Tx = 2-2x$, if $ x \in ( \frac{1}{2} , 1] $. We say that a map is topologically transitive if, for any pair $U, V$ of nonempty open subsets of $X$, there exists some $n\ge0$ such that $T^{n}(U) \cap V \neq \varnothing$. I need to show that $T$ is topologically transitive.

My attempt was to show that for any open and nonempty subset of $X$, say $U$, there exists $n\ge0$ such that $T^n(U)=[0,1]$ and then for any open and nonempty subset of $X$, say $V$, $T^n(U)\cap V=[0,1]\cap V=V\neq \varnothing$. What I have tried so far is to do this by cases:

First I suppose $U$ is an open interval containing $\frac{1}{2}$. Observe that $T(U)$ contains $T(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$ and $T^{2}(U)$ contains $T(T( \frac{1}{2}))=T(1)=0$, so $T^{2} (U)$ is an interval which contains the number $0$, so $[0,a]\subseteq T^{2}(U)$ for some $a\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. We also observe that $T$ is doubling the length of the interval $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ as we iterate it. So, there exists $n\ge0$ such that $T^{n+2}(U)$ is an interval which contains $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ and then $T^{n+3}(U)$ contains $0,1$ which show that $T^{n+3}(U)=[0,1]$.

The second case is if $U$ is an open subinterval of $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. In this case we observe that $T$ is doubling the length of the interval, as we iterate it and it gets to a point that there exists some $n\ge0$ such that $\frac{1}{2}\in T^n(U)$, so from the first case there exists some $m\ge0$ such that $T^m(T^n(U))=[0,1]\implies T^{m+n}(U)=[0,1]$.

The third case is that $U=(a,b)\subseteq(\frac{1}{2},1)$, then $T(U)=(2-2b, 2-2a)$. We observe that $T(U)$ is double the length of the interval $(a,b)$. I want to show that there exists a $n\ge0$ such that $\frac{3}{4} \in T^n(U)$ and then $T(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{1}{2}\in T^{n+1}(U)$, so I apply the first case again. This is where I got stuck and I don't know how to continue. I would appreciate any help with this, or any other kind of solution.

Comment: Please take a look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post, with particular emphasis on the heading *Use Paragraphs*.

Comment: And strictly speaking this is *not* the same as topological transitivity. "Topologically transitive implies (your definition)" is true if the space has no isolated points, but not in general. Your definition implies topological transitivity when the space is metrisable. As $[0,1]$ satisfies both conditions, it is ok to use your definition here, but be warned it is not ok in general

Comment: Reference: "[Operator theoretic aspects of ergodic theory](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~eisner/book-EFHN.pdf)"

Comment: @FShrike I'm currently reading the first chapter of Grosse-Erdmann & Peris Manguillot's book Linear Chaos, which chapter is about topological dynamical systems and this is the definition that gives for a map to be topologically transitive

Comment: Reference:[link] (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-2170-1)

Comment: Well, I suppose this is a different convention. Nevermind! Our sources agree on the definition for this particular space $[0,1]$

Comment: My book leaves it as the same exercise. Their hint is that for any nontrivial closed subinterval $I\subseteq[0,1]$ there is $n\in\Bbb N$ with $T^nI=[0,1]$. Once you show this, the result is quite immediate

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297513/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1798658/169085, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1798344/169085

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4110020/169085

Answer (score 3):

First we need, as you suspected and attempted, the lemma:

> $I\subseteq[0,1]$ is a nontrivial closed interval, $T^n(I)=[0,1]$ eventually.

Core to the proof is that the continuous image of an interval is an interval.

Proof:

> Suppose $0\in I$, so $I=[0,a]$ for some $a$. For some $n$ we will then have, for some $x$, $T^n(I)=[0,x]\supseteq[0,1/2]$ and then $T^{n+1}(I)=[0,1]$. Now suppose $I\subseteq(0,1/2]$. After some number of iterations $n$ clearly we will have either $T^n(I)$ straddling $1/2$ or $T^n(I)\subseteq[1/2,1]$. We treat the latter case last.
>
> For the former, let $T^n(I)=[a,b]$, and then the hypothesis is that $a\lt\frac{1}{2}\lt b$. $T^{n+1}(I)$ will then equal $[x,1]$ for some $x$; $T^{n+2}(I)$ will equal $[0,y]$ for some $y$ and we have already covered this case.
>
> Finally suppose $I=[a,b]$,$1/2\lt a\lt b\lt1$ (the case when the interval contains $1$ has already been covered, and if the interval contains $1/2$ its next time iterate contains $1$). Our dream is to get this interval into one of the already seen forms - this dream fails if and only if $T^n(I)$ remains in the above form for all $n$. Let’s analyse this failure: consider that $1/2\lt T(x)\lt 1$ and $1/2\lt x\lt1$ implies further that $1/2\lt x\lt3/4$. What if $1/2\lt T^2(x)\lt1$ as well? Then $1/2\lt T(x)\lt3/4$ and $5/8\lt x\lt3/4$ - the possibilities for $x$ are shrinking.
>
> These numbers come from solving $2-2x=y$, which is testing the assumption that for all $x\in I$, the *orbit* of $x$ is strictly between $1/2$ and $1$ so that the action of $T$ is *always* $x\mapsto2-2x$ on this orbit. $2-2x=y\implies x=1-y/2$, and thus the preimage of any interval $(c,d)$ by this map is $(1-d/2,1-c/2)$ which has length $(d-c)/2$. Thus the infinite intersection of preimages can have at most one point ($2/3$, in fact), since the diameter vanishes ($1/2,1/4,1/8,\cdots\to0$). However, as a nontrivial interval, $I$ *cannot* have only one point, so it is impossible that every element of $I$ should have the *entirety* of its orbit contained in $(1/2,1)$.
>
> Accordingly, our dream never fails, and $I$ evolves over time into one of the already-covered cases. The event that $I$ gets caught in a loop, i.e. always going from the case $I\subset(1/2,1)$ to the case $I\subset(0,1/2)$ and back, is impossible by similar argument. $\blacksquare$

With this lemma in hand, note that if $U,V$ are any two nonempty open subsets of $[0,1]$ then $U$ must contain a point $x_0\in[0,1]$ and an open interval $(x_0-r,x_0+r)$ for some $r\gt0$, and it must contain the nontrivial closed interval $I:=[x_0-r/2,x_0+r/2]$. Using the lemma, as: $$\emptyset\neq V\cap[0,1]=V\cap T^n(I)\subseteq V\cap T^n(U)$$For some $n\in\Bbb N$, the claim holds and we are done by the arbitrariness of $U,V$.

Comment: Could you please explain why after n iterations we we have either $T^{n}(I)$ straddling $\frac{1}{2}$ or $T^{n} (I) \subseteq [ \frac {1}{2} , 1] $ ?

Comment: @JustTry The endpoints would keep doubling, would keep increasing. Let $I=[a,b]$ with $0\lt a\lt b\le1/2$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be the unique $n$ with $1\gt2^n b\gt1/2$. Notice that since this means $T^{n-1}(b)\lt1/2$, the action of $T$ has only been to double (thus far). If $2^n a\lt1/2$, then we have $T^n(I)=[2^n a,2^n b]$ and it straddles $1/2$. If $2^n a\gt1/2$, then $T^n(I)=[2^n a,2^n b]\supseteq[1/2,1]$

Comment: *Excuse me, there should be some equality signs: $1\ge2^n b\ge1/2$ and $T^{n-1}(b)\le1/2$. You can analytically identify this unique $n$ as: $n=\lfloor\log_2(1/x)-1\rfloor$ but that is just a little extra, it is not necessary.

Comment: Could you please also explain a little bit more about the last part where you take the preimages of open sets of the form (c,d)? Why do you take those preimages and which are those preimages? Why the diameter vanishes to zero?

Comment: In the last section, we are given $I\subseteq(1/2,1)$ and we are faced with the problem: is it possible that $T^n(I)\subseteq(1/2,1)$ for all $n$? In such a case, *the action of $T$ is to just apply $x\mapsto2-2x$*, since we are *always* within $(1/2,1)$. Let $f:x\mapsto2-2x$. The condition that $I$ is always in this range is equivalent to $I\subseteq\bigcap_{n\ge0}f^{-n}(1/2,1)$. However, as $|f^{-1}(c,d)|=(d-c)/2$ for any interval $(c,d)$, $|f^{-n}(c,d)|=2^{-n}(d-c)$ and these vanish as $n\to\infty$. It is therefore impossible that the set of intersections has more than on element

Comment: As a side note, $\bigcap_{n\ge0}f^{-n}(1/2,1)=\{2/3\}$. The point is, it has *at most* $1$ element so $I$, as a nontrivial interval, cannot be a subset. Therefore there exists $n$ such that $T^n(I)\not\subset(1/2,1)$, therefore we eventually evolve into one of the already seen cases - done. @JustTry